# Create dynamic object with push

Tags: javascript

I have requirement like:

```
Item1-  Orange color  3 pic  
        Pink   color  5 pic  
Item2-  White color   9 pi  
        Black color   8 pic
```

I want to create an object and dynamically  push Items.
I have tried with

```
var data = {items: [
    {id: "1", Color: "Orange", Qty: "3"},
    {id: "2", Color: "Yellow", Qty: "2"},     
]};
```

But I can not add multiple color of an Item.

Comment: It's unclear what you want the end result to look like, not the least because the code doesn't match the example requirement. What does "can not add multiple color of an item" mean? Where is the code where you have tried to push the items?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var data = {item1: [],item2: []};

//pushing to item1
data.item1.push({id: "1", Color: "Orange", Qty: "3"});
data.item1.push({id: "2", Color: "Yellow", Qty: "2"});

//pushing to item2
data.item2.push({id: "1", Color: "Orange", Qty: "3"});
data.item2.push({id: "2", Color: "Yellow", Qty: "2"});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean, you have several items each one with several varieties. In that case, this is the right structure:

```
var items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        variety: [
            {color: 'orange', qty: 3},
            {color: 'pink',   qty: 5}
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        variety: [
            {color: 'white', qty: 9},
            {color: 'black', qty: 8}
        ]
    }
];
```

For pushing data, you just have to use the method `push()` of the `Array` prototype this way:

```
// Pushing items
items.push({
    id: 3,
    variety: [
        {color: 'red', qty: 1}
    ]
});
// Pushing varieties
items[2].variety.push({color: 'green', qty: 6});
```

The result of the previous operations sets `items`this way:

```
var items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        variety: [
            {color: 'orange', qty: 3},
            {color: 'pink',   qty: 5}
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        variety: [
            {color: 'white', qty: 9},
            {color: 'black', qty: 8}
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        variety: [
            {color: 'red',   qty: 1},
            {color: 'green', qty: 6}
        ]
    }
];
```